# Prove this sequence is Non-Cauchy

Tags: analysis, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to solve this question but am finding it difficult to prove. I am using the negation of the Cauchy definition for sequences

$\exists >, \forall ∈\mathbb Z^+, \exists n,m>N, |a_n-a_m|\geq\epsilon$
for the integers
$n\geq1, a_n=\sin(3n+1)$

Not sure how I need to manipulate the trig part of it to get my epsilon

Comment: $(3n+1)\mod 2\pi$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I have learnt that yet. But I will have a look

Comment: Are you sure you copied it right? Normally the epsilon goes with the "forall" quantifier.

Comment: Let $b_n\in [0,2\pi)$ be such that $3n+1 = k\cdot 2\pi + b_n$ with $k\in\mathbb N$. Then $b_n$ comes as close to any number in $[0,2\pi)$ as you want. That's what it means.

Comment: @ Jorge Fernandez Hidalgo: what he has is the negation of the Cauchy condition. Hence the $\exists$ instead of $\forall$, etc.

Comment: Ahh yes I'll edit that now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I messed up I'm sorry buddy.

Comment: It's too early for maths haha. Yes my original statement was indeed fine. I forgot I was talking about negation

Comment: @LukeXu In China (or wherever you are) it might be too early. Here its 11:35 pm.